# confusion/question for attack power description in character builder

Tags: dnd-4e, attack

I'm confused as to the description of some of the attack powers for my players' characters. I'm using Wizards character builder for this so im referring to their attack power cards they include in your character sheets.

For instance, the cavalier's "Vengeful Strike." At the top of the card it lists the cavalier's warhammer weapon It read: (warhammer: +8 vs. AC, 1d10+6 damage).  Then follows the colorful description of the attack followed by the keywords.

**The following spot is where I get confused:** the "Attack" is listed as Strength vs AC, which is listed as being a +8 to hit and 1 d10+6 damage like listed above. However the description as to what happens if it hits is as follows: Hit: 1{W} + Strength modifier (+5) radiant damage. If at least one bloodied ally is within 5 squares of you, the target takes extra radiant damage equal to your Cha modidfer (+2).

My question is **why is he only getting a +5 strength modifier when it should be a +6?** His strength vs AC for basic attack is a +6 so why is this attack power only a +5? Do I follow the damage done for the attack power description or just what's listed at the very top of the card? Warhammer +8 vs ac 1 d10+6 damage?

Comment: Presumably he has something else giving him a damage bonus.

Comment: What are you Cav's feats?

Comment: Does your Cav wield a magic weapon of some kind? that would account for the to-hit and damage.

Comment: He does have a feat which gives him +1 to damage when using a warhammer. So does that mean I add the +1 to the +5 stated in the attack power's description? I thought the character builder attack power cards have everything built/accounted for in the attack descriptions. But maybe this isnt the case?

Comment: @Brett The character builder does factor it all in, but it does so in the math summation lines ("Warhammer +8 vs AC 1d10+6 damage") The power itself is written correctly, as the power only grands you the str mod bonuses, other bonuses are coming from feats and weapon prof. Since those bonuses were never part of the powercard itself, they would not be included in the powercard description (beyond the math line). Otherwise every powercard would be the compendium itself.

Comment: @Brett and I'm guessing y'all are Level 2 right? unless he's human and has an expertise feat as well? But yeah, what Jas said, the builder does the math for you and it's almost always right.

Comment: thanks everyone for answering. Yes he is a level 2. Wax eagle and Joshua, thanks for the precise and helpful info. I may conjure up another question in the near future and i really appreciate the quick feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Ok,

There are two possibilities, either your Cav is Level 2 with a mundane war hammer and a damage feat (Weapon Focus(Bludgeon) is the likely one). Or he has a +1 magic warhammer of some kind.

Let me break down the math for you (L2 with the feat)

- To hit:

  strength mod (+5) + Weapon proficiency (+2) + 1/2 level (+1)
- Damage

  Strength mod (+5) + Weapon Focus (+1)

OR (L1 with a magic weapon)

- To hit:

  strength mod (+5) + Weapon proficiency (+2) + weapon enhancement (+1)
- Damage

  Strength mod (+5) + Weapon enhancement (+1)

Comment: Thank you wax eagle. This is a wonderful place for questions